# SQL Insert record on For each record of the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, while-loop

Need some advise on the scenario below. I have two joined tables (say table A and Table B)

Table A has the column ContrastId while Table B has HueID, they were joined by ColorId

```
Select ColorCD, ContrastId, HueId, 
From TableA TA
Inner JOIN TableB TB
TA.ColorID = TB.ColorID
```

The results of the above select statement should be inserted to another table (say Table C)

Example of results:

```
ColorCD | ContrastID | HueID
-----------------------------
111000  | 123        |  555
111100  | 114        | 548
110015  | 128        | 265
```

What I want to happened in the Table C, where in I need to put the result set is shown below.

Table C

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TableC (Gen_N, ColorCD,  ColorType ,Identifier, ProcessDT)
            SELECT Gen_N, ColorCD,  'Contrast' ,Identifier, ProcessDT
            From TableA TA
            Inner JOIN TableB TB
            TA.ColorID = TB.ColorID


Gen_N | ColorCD  | ColorType | Identifier
------------------------------------------    
Color | 111000   | Contrast  | 123
Color | 111000   | Hue       | 555
Color | 111100   | Contrast  | 148
Color | 111100   | Hue       | 548
Color | 110015   | Contrast  | 128
Color | 110015   | Hue       | 256
```

Apologies on the layout, I don't know how to insert a table here. :) Thanks a lot for the help. I believe I need to do a loop here to get every record of the result set just not sure how to.

Any help please? Thanks a lot

Comment: What are the values for the column `ProcessDT`??

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a loop for this.  Assuming your fields are correct, you can do this `Insert` with a `Union` for each of the types.

This should work for the implied structure:

```
Insert  TableC (Gen_N, ColorCD, ColorType, Identifier, ProcessDT)
    Select  Gen_N, ColorCD, 'Contrast', ContrastId, ProcessDT
    From    TableA  TA
    Join    TableB  TB  On  TA.ColorID = TB.ColorID
Union All
    Select  Gen_N, ColorCD, 'Hue', HueID, ProcessDT
    From    TableA  TA
    Join    TableB  TB  On  TA.ColorID = TB.ColorID
```